# Highcharts columnrange with strange height/width for columns

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a column chart (Highcharts) with a fixed width (range) for all the columns. I have around 300 columns, and I want to draw them actually as lines, and that's why I assign a very small range (0.001) for each of them.

The data format is basically like this: [numberId, min, max].

However, sometimes the height is shown correctly... but some other times it appears with strange height, not even the same for all the columns. I have tried many different things but I didn't manage to find the problem.

This is the jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/deSSf/3/ (if you resize the area for the chart you will probably see the effect). The fiddle is actually using HighStock, but this chart should be from highcharts lib.

I have screenshos but can't post them.

The code is very simple:

```
   chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'columnrange',
    },

    series: [{
        data: [[1,0,0.001],......]]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is huge difference between Highcharts and Highstock. In Highstock you have access to [dataGrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation) which collects data and groups when there is to many points to display on a chart.

Disable it to have working example: http://jsfiddle.net/deSSf/4/

```
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it. Actually I had a more complex chart than the one in the jdfiddle, and I have already set dataGrouping=false for column charts, but I forgot doing the same for columnrange charts.